# Calling from PHP Stored Procedure with Cursor and Union SQL Doesn't Show All Data

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedures, mysqli, cursor

I Create a stored procedure that execute perfectly in MYSQL but when I call it from PHP it only show the data that correspond to the first data of the cursor.

Here is how I call the stored procedure :

```
$sql = mysqli_query($db, "CALL MySP('".$ec4."')");
```

Here is how I retrieve the data:

```
while ($ligne = mysqli_fetch_array($sql))
```

Thank you

[Stored procedure data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LLcRZ.png)

[php calling](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DjsA8.png)

```
while ($ligne = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)) {                 
                    echo '</br>';
                    echo '</br>'.$ligne["Agences"].'</br>';
                    echo '</br>'.$ligne["date_op"].'</br>';
                    echo '</br>'.$ligne["arrivee"].'</br>';
                    }
```

Here is my Stored Procedure :

```
DELIMITER $
CREATE PROCEDURE `MySP`( date_op VARCHAR(10) ) 
BEGIN
DECLARE done INT DEFAULT FALSE;
DECLARE ville_agence VARCHAR(50);    
DECLARE cursor_i CURSOR FOR SELECT ville FROM villes;
DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = TRUE;
OPEN cursor_i;
read_loop: LOOP
    FETCH cursor_i INTO ville_agence;
    IF done THEN
      LEAVE read_loop;
    END IF;
        SELECT
        Agences, 
        date_op,
        (select Villes from grille a where a.Nom = b.Nom_de_Depart and a.`Type` ='A' LIMIT 1) as arrivee
        FROM 
        grille b
        where 
        b.`Type` = 'T'
        and upper(Agences) in (ville_agence)

        UNION

        SELECT 
        Agences,
        date_op,
        (select Agences from grille a where a.Code = b.Code and a.`Type` = 'D' LIMIT 1) as arrivee
        FROM 
        grille b
        where  b.`Type` = 'A'
        and upper(Agences) in (ville_agence);
  END LOOP;
  CLOSE cursor_i;
END
```

Comment: And what output do you get when iterating over `mysqli_fetch_array()`?

Comment: My cursor fetch a table with 2 rows , but the mysqli_fetch_array show me only the data that correspond to the first row and not the second one. in Mysql when I execute the stored procedure, it show me all the data. I think that the problem is with mysqli_fetch_array.

Comment: Could you include the result of the stored procedure, and show us what you're doing with the data inside of the while?

Comment: Hi Daniel, thank you for your interest, I just add the pictures to the Question.

Comment: Hi Guys,I found the solution to my problem, i had to use : 
if (mysqli_multi_query($con,$sql))
{
  do
    {
   if ($result=mysqli_store_result($con)) {
      while ($row=mysqli_fetch_row($result))
        {
        printf("%s\n",$row[0]);
        }
      mysqli_free_result($result);
      }
    } while (mysqli_next_result($con));
} Hope it will help Others .

Comment: You can answer your own question, and mark it as accepted.